# How can I add a edittext to a gridview?

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, android-edittext

I have a GridView which is filtered by a Spinner. I need add into the GridView two EditTexts per Row and I don't know how. Example:

[image: img]

activity_main.xml

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.pruebalistview.MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/combobox"
    android:layout_width="303dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="40dp"
    android:layout_y="20dp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="254dp"
    android:layout_x="54dp"
    android:layout_y="184dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
</GridView>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
        package com.example.pruebalistview;

        import java.util.ArrayList;





        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
        import android.widget.TableLayout;
        import android.widget.TableRow;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spMarca= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combobox);
        final ArrayList<Articulos2> articulos2 = new ArrayList<Articulos2>();
        ArrayList<String> marcaLista = new ArrayList<String>();

            Articulos2 art1 = new Articulos2("XP006200", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.3", "SOCOLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 74.00);
            Articulos2 art2 = new Articulos2("XP006200", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.3", "SOCOLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 74.00);
            Articulos2 art3 = new Articulos2("XP006200", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.3", "SOCOLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 74.00);
            Articulos2 art4 = new Articulos2("XP006200", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.3", "SOCOLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 74.00);
            Articulos2 art5 = new Articulos2("XP006100", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.0", "MASTER COLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 64.00);
            Articulos2 art6 = new Articulos2("XP006100", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.0", "MASTER COLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 64.00);
            Articulos2 art7 = new Articulos2("XP006100", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.0", "MASTER COLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 64.00);
            Articulos2 art8 = new Articulos2("XP006100", "SOCOLOR.BEAUTY 6.0", "MASTER COLOR", "SOCOLOR PIGMENTS", "SOCOLOR", 2, 64.00);
            articulos2.add(art1);
            articulos2.add(art2);
            articulos2.add(art3);
            articulos2.add(art4);
            articulos2.add(art5);
            articulos2.add(art6);
            articulos2.add(art7);
            articulos2.add(art8);

    marcaLista.add("Todas");
            for (int i=0; i < articulos2.size(); i++){
                if (!marcaLista.contains(articulos2.get(i).getMarca())){
                    marcaLista.add(articulos2.get(i).getMarca());
                }
            }

    final GridView grilla = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv); 
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


        ArrayAdapter<String> rubrosAdaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, marcaLista);
        spMarca.setAdapter(rubrosAdaptador);

    spMarca.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Haz seleccionado " + arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                adapter.clear();

                for (int i=0; i<articulos2.size();i++){ 

                    if (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString().equals("Todas")){
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getCodigo());
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getDescripcion());
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getPrecio().toString());
                    }

                    if (articulos2.get(i).getMarca().contains(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString())){
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getCodigo());
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getDescripcion());
                        adapter.add(articulos2.get(i).getPrecio().toString());


                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        grilla.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   }
```

This code just shows a gridview filtered by a spinner.